# MySQL: update column every year

Tags: sql, mysql, triggers

I have a table with different types of wine and I want the price of older wines to increase every year, can i do it with a trigger?

This is the definition of the Wine table:

```
create table Bottiglia(
    codice bigint(8) unsigned not null,
    tipo_bottiglia varchar(20) not null,
    produttore bigint(11) unsigned not null,
    annata year not null,
    qta_disponibile int not null,
    costo decimal(5, 2) not null,
    primary key(codice),
    foreign key(produttore) references Produttore(p_iva)
    on delete cascade
    on update cascade
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I was thinking of using an update trigger, like this in SQL:

```
create trigger Update_Costo_Vino 
before update of costo on Bottiglia
for each row
    when old.annata >= 2018 
declare anno year;
declare var int;
begin
    set anno = year(current_date());
    set var = new.anno - old.anno;
    if var >= 1 then
        set new.costo = old.costo + (old.costo * (0.25 * var));
    end if;
end;
```

But I don't know how to do it in MySQL or even if this is a good solution for what i want to do, some suggestions?

Comment: You tagged it as SQL but also MYSQL, which one is it?  It's not both.

Comment: You can do it with Event Scheduler and have it set to run every year.

Comment: Here is how to set up the event found on this link -->
https://www.w3schools.in/mysql/event-scheduler
Also I hope you are using MySQL Workbench found here -->
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/  (if it is indeed MySQL and not just SQL you need)

Comment: @easleyfixed SQL is broad category that includes mysql.  Maybe you are thinking of SQL Server, which has its own tag sql-server and is indeed different than mysql.

Comment: consider not doing this; instead have a base_costo column and a generated column costo as `(round(base_costo * pow(1.25, year(current_date)-anno), 2))` (though I would recommend not using current_date, which changes based on session time zone, but instead utc_timestamp.  or if you want the year in some specific timezone, something like `year(convert_tz(utc_timestamp,'+00:00','Europe/Rome'))`)

Comment: @ysth yes but why tag everything possible because it exist and why not tag the exact type you are using instead?  SQL formatted code and MYSQL formatted code are not identical in all cases.

Comment: Do NOT alter the table data. You have initial price value and year value, you know current year value, so you may easily calculate current price (see @ysth's comment). Moreover, the increasing coefficient may differ for current year depends on the vine age (for example the price for 2023-year vine may increase by 5% whereas for 1983-year vine it can be 10%) - in this case you'd have a table which stores (production year - current year - coefficient).

Comment: @easleyfixed I’m sorry I’m new, here, I tagged both because I need the MySQL code, but the trigger example I reported is in SQL

Comment: thanks so much for yours replies, I think the event scheduler is the perfect solution

Comment: @easleyfixed yes, I don't see a lot of purpose in the sql tag